# Collating data in r

Tags: r, formatting

I have data that looks like this:

```
Value   Species
1       warb
1       warb
2       warb
3       tit
2       tit
3       tit
```

and i want it to look like

```
warb   tit
1      3
1      2
2      3
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, I would just suggest `unstack`:

```
unstack(mydf)
#   tit warb
# 1   3    1
# 2   2    1
# 3   3    2
```

Since this is essentially a reshaping problem, you can also consider adding an ID column based on "Species" (easy with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package) and then reshaping to a "wide" form.

Examples:

```
library(splitstackshape) ## mostly for getanID
dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, "Species"), 
                 .id ~ Species, value.var = "Value")
#    .id tit warb
# 1:   1   3    1
# 2:   2   2    1
# 3:   3   3    2

reshape(getanID(mydf, "Species"), 
        direction = "wide", idvar = ".id", 
        timevar = "Species")
#    .id Value.warb Value.tit
# 1:   1          1         3
# 2:   2          1         2
# 3:   3          2         3
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is

```
Value<-c(1,1,2,3,2,3)
Species<-c("warb","warb","warb","tit","tit","tit")
df<-data.frame(Value,Species)
```

try

```
result <- as.data.frame(tapply(df$Value,df$Species,list))
```

Comment: Or use `split` i.e. `as.data.frame(split(df$Value, df$Species))`